# Can log on to network-computer from another one even when "Network discovery" is off

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

Using `"Network and sharing center - advanced sharing settings"` I turned on `"Network discovery"` and `"file and printer sharing"` on my Windows 7 and Windows 8 computers ("Win7" and "Win8"). The computers are both networked to my wireless router.

I then logged on from Win8 - onto Win7, and could browse the folders there.

**Here is where the trouble started:**

I turned **off** "Network discovery" and "file and printer sharing" on Win7 - **but could still log on to it** from Win8! Also, even though I did **not** save the username and password - I could log on without needing to supply it. Only after restarting Win7 did that not persist.

Is that expected behavior? Will network-discovery persist for whoever has already logged on once? (Or was it some bug.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem has gone, the settings most likely didn't take effect until the restart, where the network services reloaded their settings.

And your were able to login without a password because it was most likely cached from the first login. Or, in other words, you weren't really logged out.